# show price based on product selected in form box

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model of product and sale. A product contains a list of product with name, price and quantity where a sales model has product(Foreign key), quantity and price. There is a form for sale which shows list of products, quantity and price. Whenever a user selects for the product, the price field should show the price of that product and which should be uneditable. How can it be done?

My code

**Product**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, help_text="name of the product")
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    price =  models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**product/forms.py**

```
PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, 21)]

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

**product/views.py**

```
def add_product(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            # product = form.save(commit=false)
            # product.save()
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            price = form.cleaned_data['price']
            quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            Product.objects.create(name=name, quantity=quantity, price=price)
            messages.success(request, 'Product is successfully added.')
            return redirect('/product/')
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, 'product/product_add.html', {'form':form})
```

**sales/models.py**

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    price =  models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

**sales/forms.py**

```
class SaleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = '__all__'
```

In the image(sale form), i have selected the product shoe and its price is say $70, now after selecting the product shoe my price box should show $70 inside it. Likewise, if i selected the product football, the price box should show price of football. 
[image]

**UPDATE**

**sales/urls.py**

```
url(r'^price/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.fetch_price, name='fetch_price'),
```

**sales/views.py for ajax**

```
def add_sale(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = SaleForm(request.POST or None)
        form.fields['price'].widget.attrs['disabled']=True
        if form.is_valid():
            # product = form.save(commit=false)
            # product.save()
            product = form.cleaned_data['product']
            price = form.cleaned_data['price']
            quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
            Sale.objects.create(product=product, quantity=quantity, price=price)
            messages.success(request, 'Product is successfully sold.')
            return redirect('/product/')
    else:
        form = SaleForm()
    return render(request, 'sale/add_sale.html', {'form':form})


def fetch_price(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    print('product',product)
    if request.method=='GET':
        response = HttpResponse('')
        price = product.price
        print('price',price)
        response['price-pk'] = product.pk
        response['price'] = price 
        return response
```

**add_sale.html**

```
<script>
        $('#id_product').on('change', function() {
            price_value = $(this).val();
            console.log(price_value);
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'/sale/price/'+price_value+"/",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('price will be updated based on product selected');
                    $('#id_price').val(data.price);
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

This way i get 404 error

Comment: Can you add the code(views.py and HTML template) where products are listed to selection?

Comment: sorry my mind was not working so i wrote a wrong question. I have updated it. Wait i will update the code with templates. I have already posted the views part.

Comment: @SivasubramaniamArunachalam i have updated my question with an image too. The image is of sales form. I want price to be listed on price box based on the product selected.

Comment: @Serenity Hi, I know this is quite old, but I am going through the same issue. Would you mind sharing the HTML part? It will be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Nope!

**This will cause so many requests to the server for only showing product price!**

Best practice to always **minimize requests** as much as could to imporve website performance.

Now answering your question in regards fetching price:

In your html, in products for loop, **add special tag to present product price in options**..

For example:

```
         {% for item in products %}
          <select class="products">
                <option price="{{ item.price }}">
                      {{ item.name }}
                </option>
           </select>
          {% endfor %}
```

Now last step is to render product price according to selection with Javascript!

```
    $(document).on("change", '.products', function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           $('#id_price').val($(this).children(":selected").attr("price"));
    });
```

Before doing any ajax/request to the server, always think if this can be done in free SQL queries method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to disable a form field.

```
form = SaleForm()
form.fields['price'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```

This just disable it in front end only. You have to o validations in backend form validation because, in frontend anyone can do disable to enable.

Comment: How the price field will be filled up with the price value of the product being selected?

Comment: I want the price value in the price field based on the product being selected. Like in image, the product of shoe is selected and it worth $70. So the price field should show $70 before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You should write javascript code to detect the `onchange` event of the `product` field. In the `onchange` event handler, you should fire the AJAX call to the backend to fetch the information for the selected product by passing the `product_id`. Typically, this is an another view function called from `urls.py`. Once the backend responds, the callback of AJAX call should update the `price` field. You can consider using `jQuery` instead of plain `javascript` to ease the implementation.

Comment: so i should use $.get and fetch the price based on the product_id that i get from the selected product?

Comment: Yes. This should be easier way

Comment: Search Google with "django ajax". You will get plenty of examples. Can you please try as much as you can? You can post the code if it is not working.

Comment: Inside sales/views.py i added this view logic def fetch_price(request, pk):
 product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
 print('product',product)
 if request.method=='GET':
  response = HttpResponse('')
  price = product.price
  print('price',price)
  response['price-pk'] = product.pk
  response['price'] = price 
  return response

now how can i pass pk to ajax get url ?

Comment: i fetched the correct id of the selected product. I get the correct product instance and price too in terminal which i printed inside views of fetch_price. But i get 404 error.

Comment: I have updated my question with fetch_price views, urls.py and ajax code.